# Drop Down Content/Table and Page Jumping

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a page with several dynamic/sortable tables in it (one below another) to share PDF documents. Each Document tittle in the table contain a link to open the PDF in a new tab. Everything works fine, BUT when I scroll down the page and open a dynamic table/or minimize the table, the page jumps to top of the page/to default position. JavaScript's RETURN FALSE fixes this problem but all the links in the table are dead. Can anyone help to fix this? I attach the basic code structure here you can see what I am doing...

HTML:

```
<div id ="fifth">
<ul id="droptable">
        <li><a href="#"><h1>Tittle of The Dynamic Table5</h1></a>
<div>
<table class="sortable" width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="tablehead" width="55%">Sort by tittle</td>
<td id="tablehead" width="25%">Sort by Author</td>
<td id="tablehead" width="25%">Sort by date</td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="tabledata" width="55%"><a href="document1.pdf" target="_blank">Document1Name</td>
<td id="tabledata" width="25%">AuthorX</td>
<td id="tabledata" width="25%">DateX</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="tabledata" width="55%"><a href="document2.pdf" target="_blank">Document2Name</td>
<td id="tabledata" width="25%">AuthorX</td>
<td id="tabledata" width="25%">DateX</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="tabledata" width="55%"><a href="document3.pdf" target="_blank">Document3Name</td>
<td id="tabledata" width="25%">AuthorX</td>
<td id="tabledata" width="25%">DateX<a></td>
</tr>
</table>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul> 

</div>
```

---

JAVASCRIPT:

```
// Dropdown Table Code
$(function(){
$('#droptable li a').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
$(this).siblings('div').slideToggle(300); // If I add RETURN FALSE here the page doesn't jump to the default position/to the top of the page (when open or minimize the table) BUT links in the table are out and don't work anymore //
  });        
  });                
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things

1st id's should be unique, so change all instances of

```
 id="tabledata"
```

to

```
 class="tabledata"
```

2nd, try to give you td's that contain the link a different class than those that have data, then attach slide toggle to that class, maybe like:

```
$('.newclass').each(function(){
 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't succeed with the hints you gave but thanks anyway! I did everything but page was still jumping when opening/closing the table. BUT...I was browsing different forums and found this simple answer.

Using "#/" instead of "#" and the page won't jump. Hmm.. sometimes the answer is too simple, seemingly :o

```
<div id ="fifth">
<ul id="droptable">
    <li><a href="#/"><h1>Tittle of The Dynamic Table5</h1></a> ...
```

Rock'nRoll!